# Как автоматически заполнить форму на другом сайте?

Tags: php, javascript

Добрый день.

Собственно, постала передомной непростая задачка.

Имеется некий сайт такси (другой фирмы), и есть мой сайт (есть форма аналогичная конкуренту для заказов).
Иногда на некоторое время я сам не могу обрабатывать запросы, и мне необходимо скидывать заказы на конкурента, то есть автоматически заполнить его форму.

Как мне, зная метод "post", имя формы и имена полей на сайте конкурента, автоматически заполнить их?
Может, кто знает пример заполнения такой формы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С помощью, к примеру, **curl** отправлять **POST** запрос.

**Обновление**

Параметры: a=4&b=7

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://mysite.ru/receiver.php');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "a=4&b=7");
$out = curl_exec($curl);
echo $out;
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Если вам несложно, напишите пример такой отправки?

Comment: Параметры: a=4&b=7

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://mysite.ru/receiver.php');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "a=4&b=7");
    $out = curl_exec($curl);
    echo $out;
    curl_close($curl);